# JMH Collections Copy Benchmark

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

I want to benchmark some methods of List interface in JCF with JMH. I am new to JMH. I read the samples code provided at JMH website.
In my code, I want to see how much time is required for adding elements from one list to another. For example, from ArrayList to LinkedList and vice versa when the source list size is either of 100, 1000, 10000 and so on.

I used Level.Iteration for setup and teardown method and clearing the lists properly. But when I print the list size of destination list (dst), I get this result:

```
Before teardown100 dst size: **2373600**  //This is the last call output
46,335 us/op


Run result: 46,33 us/op (<= 2 samples)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:05

Benchmark                                             (changeTypes)  (size)      Mode  Samples   Score  Score error  Units
d.d.t.d.b.c.CollectionCopyBenchmark.copyCollection            AL-LL     100   avgt        1  58,446          NaN  us/op
d.d.t.d.b.c.CollectionCopyBenchmark.copyCollection            LL-AL     100  avgt        1  46,335          NaN  us/op
```

Here is the code :

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 1)
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public class CollectionCopyBenchmark {

@Param({"AL-LL", "LL-AL"})
String changeTypes;


//@Param({"100", "1000", "10000", "100000"})
@Param({"100"})
int size;


private Collection src, dst;

Collection<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();
Collection<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();


@Setup(Level.Iteration)
public void setup(){
    String[] str = changeTypes.split("-");

    String srcCollection = str[0];
    String dstCollection = str[1];

    al.clear();
    ll.clear();


    switch (srcCollection) {
        case "LL" :     src = ll; break;
        case "AL" :     src = al; break;
    }

    switch (dstCollection) {
        case "LL" :     dst = ll; break;
        case "AL" :     dst = al; break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        src.add(i);
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void copyCollection(Blackhole bh) {
    dst.addAll(src);
    System.out.println(dst.size());
    bh.consume(dst.size());

}

@TearDown(Level.Iteration)
public void tearDown() {
    System.out.println("Before teardown" + src.size() + " dst size: "+ dst.size());
    src.clear();
    dst.clear();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(CollectionCopyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
}
}
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why I am getting 2373600 as size of the destination list?

When I use Level.Invocation, I get different output. I am confused between Invocation and Interation levels. If I want to calculate average time of a benchmark method for different list size, which level should I consider?

Comment: Your lists are not being cleared, I suspect they are only being clearer are each run, not each iteration. `clear()` is very cheap so I would try call this inside the benchmark at the start. BTW By comparison `System.out.println` is pretty expensive.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue using Level.Invocation in tearDown(), but setup() has only default Level. This way, I do not have to call clear() inside benchmark method. I am not sure, why use of Level.Invocation is discouraged. Anyone knows?

Comment: Read warnings at: http://javadox.com/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-core/1.7/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Level.html